# PHP or MySQL wont update database

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys so I have been trying to figure out why my update function wont update my database.

Here is the function:

```
public function update() {

    if ( is_null( $this->id ) ) triger_error ("DailyMenuItem::update(): Attempt to update a DailyMenuItem object that does not have its ID property set.", E_USER_ERROR);

    $conn = new PDO ( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $sql = "UPDATE daily_menu SET date=FROM_UNIXTIME(:date), name=:name, description=:description, price=:price WHERE id = :id";
    $st = $conn->prepare ( $sql );
    $st->bindValue( ":name", $this->name, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":description", $this->description, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":price", $this->price, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->bindValue( ":date", $this->date, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $st->execute();
    $conn = null;
}
```

This object contains this

> DailyMenuItem Object
>   (
>       [id] => 4
>       [name] => Smoked Chicken Baguette
>       [description] => w/goat cheese
>       [price] => 13
>       [date] => 1330585200
>   )

I get no error message. It just does not update anything. Please help :)

Comment: Looking at the bindValue methods you do not appear to have a value for the where clause, that is which record to update.(WHERE id = :id)

Comment: $result = $st->execute(); to get the result of the update op

Comment: It would probably error if he wasn't binding the ID field with `column :id not found` or something of the like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to be binding id.

Could that be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In every update and delete query you need an primary key value on which you are performing query. Here in your example you have mentioned ID in the query but there is no bind below so with out the id query will not know which row to be updated.